# Referencing another docker container from next js app which is also in a docker container

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  auth-db:
    build:
      context: ./penai-backend/auth-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-auth-db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  auth-service:
    build:
      context: ./penai-backend/auth-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-auth-service
    depends_on:
      - auth-db
    container_name: auth-service

  frontend-app:
    build:
      context: ./penai-frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - auth-db
      - auth-service
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I am trying to reference auth-service in nextjs app as follows:

.env.local file :

NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_SERVICE_DOMAIN=auth-service
NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_SERVICE_PORT=8080

services.config.js file:

```
const services = {
    transcriptionService: {
        domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TRANSCRIPTION_SERVICE_DOMAIN,
        port: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TRANSCRIPTION_SERVICE_PORT
    },
    diarizationService: {
        domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DIARIZATION_SERVICE_DOMAIN,
        port: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DIARIZATION_SERVICE_PORT
    },
    authService: {
        domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_SERVICE_DOMAIN,
        port: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_SERVICE_PORT
    }
};
```

getServiceURL.js file:

```
const servicesConfig = require("../../services.config");

export function getServiceURL(serviceName) {
    const service = servicesConfig[serviceName];
    if (!service) throw new Error(`Service '${serviceName}' not found in the configuration.`);
    else return `http://${service.domain}:${service.port}`;
}
```

here is the usage:

getServiceURL("authService")

In the inspection tool of the browser, I get the following error:

auth-service:8080 net:ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Any idea for resolving this ?

module.exports = services;

I tried the following solution as described above but it did not work. Although I can connect the db container from auth-service by referring the container name. I cannot achieve this in nextjs.

Comment: The important detail here is that your Javascript code is actually running in the end user's browser.  Even if its code is served by a container, it's executing in a browser, outside Docker, with no awareness of Docker networking.  In the linked question I describe configuration options to work around this.